# With high probability versus expectation

Tags: probability

Suppose I know that a variable must be equal to 5 with high probability. Does this always imply that the expected value of that variable must be 5, too?
Can the variable have such extreme behavior that the expected value is something else?

Comment: Yes the random variable could be $5$ with $99.9\%$ probability and $10^{1000000}$ with $.1\%$. The expected value is nowhere near five. For any given "high probability" (arbitrarily close but not equal to one) the expectation could literally be anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X_n$ be a variable such that $P(X_n=5)=\frac{n-1}{n}$ and $P(X_{n}=n^2)=\frac{1}{n}$. Although for large $n$, $X_n$ is close to $5$ with high probability, $E[X_n]$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two-point distribution: $P(X=0)=1-p$ and $P(X=5)=p$, Then the expectation is $EX=5p.$ Of course $EX=5\iff p=1$. So, another values of $X$ are also allowed and their existence decreases the expectation. See also @madprob's  answer, which is a nice complement to my one.